# read cell formatting in pyexcel

Tags: python, pyexcel

Is it possible to **READ** cell formatting in pyexcel? I have to work on xls and xlsx so pyexcel seems like a good fit.

I know  you can **SET** cell formatting but I didnt find any documentation on reading cell formatting from existing excel files.

Thanks

Comment: According to [pyexcel 0.6.0 documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyexcel/) there is **nothing** about *"formatting"*?

Comment: You can definitely do this with openpyxl.

Comment: any example usage? because theres no documentation?